# Is it better to have a Util class for operations on HashSet or a Class that extends it?

Tags: java, oop

I have a `Set<Integer>` and i want to create some utility methods for it (i.e. to get the maximum, minimum etc. Is it better to have a Utility class with static methods (i.e. `int SetUtils.getMax(Set<Integer> inputSet)`) or have a class that extends an implementation of Set (i.e. `class IntegerSet extends HashSet`)?

Comment: Why don't you use a `SortedSet` instead?

Comment: @fge - thanks. I was actually googling for  that and didn't find it.. but lets say the problem is to be extended for other operations on sets or any other class for that matter. Is it better to have util classes or classes that extend?

Comment: @ArvindSridharan: Depends on the use case. Most of them are covered by `SortedSet`, `NavigableSet` and other `Set` implementations. Can you present a use case that is not covered by the implementations in `java.util` or a third party library.

Comment: Define "operation on classes"? There are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Or use `Collections.min()`.

Answer (score 3):

A utility class is more flexible; you can provide a utility method that works on any implementation of the `Set` interface. If you'd create your own subclass of `HashSet` with extra methods, then you could call those extra methods only on instances of your specific subclass.